# Enable compression for table

Tags: hbase, jdo, datanucleus

How can we enable compression for a specific table using jdo and datanucleus in hbase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the code for [that plugin](http://www.datanucleus.org/plugins/store.hbase.html), look at the class **HBaseUtils** method *createSchemaForClass* and you contribute it back. You can easily annotate a class with @Extension, and then get access to the metadata in that method using cmd.extensions. When you're done you raise an issue in JIRA and attach your patch.